# How can I I give my UIScrollView a pattern background, but with a different top?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimage, uicolor

For the text-editing part of my app, I am putting lines in a UIScrollView to simulate lined notepaper. My UIScrollView will scroll whenever the UITextView scrolls, so that the text stays fixed to the lines.

I can create 'lined paper' quite easily like so:

```
UIColor *backgroundPattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Notepaper-Line"]];
self.noteBackgroundView = scrollView; [scrollView release];
self.noteBackgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundPattern;
```

The problem is, I would like the very top line of my 'notepaper' to be different from the rest.

Looking through Apple's documentation, it seems that, in OS X, I can achieve this using `NSDrawThreePartImage`, which would allow me to make a background with fixed images for the top and bottom, and a tiled image in the middle. Is there a way for me to do this on the iPhone? Since it's going to scroll, I don't think I can just fudge it by placing another UIImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put another UIView with top pattern background on to of the UIScrollView but below UITextView, so that it covers your notepaper pattern, sized like the top pattern and positioned exactly like the text view. Like a layer in between the scroll view and text view.

Comment: This *almost* works. The only problem is that, if I pull the scrollview down with my finger (so I'm looking above the the top of the note), the line pattern starts again above the top of the note.

Comment: I see, what about making top pattern as much bigger as the maximum pull can be and positione it with negative offset so that it still covers only the appropriate region in the top?